# Having Issues with Action Mailer Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Right now I am working on building a mailer for a feature for an app built in Ruby on Rails that will send a message to an account when it hasn't checked in for a day. However I would like forgo sending said email to accounts that do not have check ins enabled.

Here is the code for sending the email to the inactive accounts:

```
def self.inactive_accounts
Account.all.select do |account|
  yesterday = (1.day.ago.beginning_of_day..1.day.ago.end_of_day)
  account.check_ins.where(worked_at: yesterday).empty?
end
```

end

```
def self.notify
 inactive_accounts.each do |account|
   MissingCheckInMailer.missing_check_in(account,1.day.ago).deliver_now
  end
end
```

What I am trying to figure out is where to start with the code that keeps these emails from being sent to accounts that do not have check in enabled.

Comment: How do you tell if check ins are enabled. ?  You can add a where.not(:checkin_enabled: true) to your query

Comment: The check ins on the account are disabled by default, you can see that an account has check ins enabled is with the query account.features

Comment: So then all you need to do is include or add a scope the only includes accounts that have check ins and the  chain it to your inactive accounts query.